# Jsp 500 Error after few seconds

Tags: hibernate, jsp, tomcat

Below is the hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://ip:3306/database</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">50</property>
   <property name="show_sql">true</property>
   <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <mapping resource="user_detail.xml"/>
  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Below is the HibernateUtil class

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
     try {
         sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
                 selectData.descLog(""+sessionFactory);
     } catch (Throwable ex) {
         System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
     }
}

public static Session openSession() {
     return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

below is the index.jsp

```
     String username = "user";
     List<user_detail> list = selectData.getData(username);

                for (user_detail detail: list)
                {
                    divertedRoute = detail.getDivertedRoute();
                    credit = detail.getRate();
                }
```

and this is selectData class

```
List<user_detail> list = null;
        try{

        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();


        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from user_detail where username = :user");
        query.setParameter("user", username);
        list =  query.list();

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            descLog("Exception caught..!!"+e.getMessage());
            writeLog(e);
        }
           return list;
```

Now the problem is when I hit index.jsp from browser then it runs perfectly. But after few seconds one time it gives me 500 error. Below is the error-

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 38
```

After again hitting I get response fine. But why this problem is coming ?
    java.lang.NullPointerException

I checked the hibernate log and found

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
```

Below is the entire stacktrace-

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/smppBalanceDeduct] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 38

35:          //   selectData sData = new selectData();
36:             List<user_detail> list = selectData.getData(username);
37:             selectData.descLog("listing is:"+list);
38:             for (user_detail detail: list)
39:             {
40:                 divertedRoute = detail.getDivertedRoute();
41:                 credit = detail.getRate();


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: ... Maybe the whole stack trace? What's null? Where?

Comment: @DaveNewton I think error is related to hibernate. when I get 500 error same time I get 'could not execute query' exception. But I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You could start by posting the entire stack trace.

Comment: I added the stacktrace. Please check